# Android Studio Gradle Error Gradle cannot sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Sorry if this has been asked before but I keep getting this error:

```
5:08 PM Gradle sync started

5:08 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
                Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}
                Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.
                Cannot create mockable android.jar
                C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (1 s 621 ms)

5:08 PM Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
                More info...
                Select a JDK from the File System
                Do not show this warning again
```

I'm also getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformException: Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}
```

Kindly asking for help!

Comment: what is the gradle versions  using?

Comment: Gradle version is 5.6..4 and Android Gradle Plugin Version is 3.6.3